# How is this equality established? (binomial/factorials)

Tags: probability, self-learning

In Rick Durrett's book, in a proof for the asymptotic behaviour of Poisson to normal, he uses the following identity:

$$\frac{n!n^m}{(n+m)!} = \left(\prod_{k=1}^m 1 + k/n  \right)^{-1}$$

I'm just wondering how this established? As Durrett states it without proof, and I am not sure how to show this.

Comment: You have $\prod_{k = 1}^m \frac{n}{n + k}$, from which the $n^m$ term is obvious. Then write out what the quotient of two factorials is.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it another go

Comment: I noticed an error in my answer so I deleted it. The correct answer is now posted. If it helps give it a big ole' check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n,m\in\Bbb N_0$, $m>n$ we define
$$\begin{align}
P(n,m)=&\prod_{k=1}^m\frac1{1+k/n}\\
=&\prod_{k=1}^m\frac{n}{n+k}\\
=&n^m\prod_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{n+k}\\
\end{align}$$
Then note that 
$$\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^{m}\frac1{n+k}=&\frac{n!}{n!}\prod_{k=1}^{m}\frac1{n+k}\\
=&\frac{n!}{n!\prod_{k=1}^{m}(n+k)}\\
=&\frac{n!}{(\prod_{r=1}^{n}r)(\prod_{k=n+1}^{n+m}k)}\\
=&\frac{n!}{\prod_{r=1}^{n+m}r}\\
=&\frac{n!}{(n+m)!}\\
\end{align}$$
So 
$$P(n,m)=\frac{n!n^m}{(n+m)!}$$